# Why does an object with static member instantiated in global namespace cause segfault?

Tags: c++

I bumped into a segmentation fault issue, that I was able to reproduce with the below shared few code lines. Class A is instantiated before the main() in the global namespace, and class A also has a static member (myMap).

If A is instantiated inside the main, or definition of the static member is placed in main.cc, there is no segmentation fault.

I would like to understand why this happens. I tried to search for possible reasons, but had no real success.

For compiling and linking the code I have simply used:   g++ main.cc mymap.cc

main.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mymap.hh"

A a;

int main()
{
   std::cout << "MyMap program is executed" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

mymap.hh

```
#include <map>

class A
{
public:
   static std::map<int,int> myMap;
   A();
};
```

mymap.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mymap.hh"

std::map<int,int> A::myMap; // defining the static member

A::A()
{
   std::cout << "A::A()" << std::endl;
   myMap[1]=1; // Segfault may occur here
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the map is at fault and not your surrounding code?
I assume your program enters UB beforehand and it just randomly crashes when it fills the map.

Comment: and you dont need to define it above constructor (last stuff). it will be defined before anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relative order of initialization of global data defined in different compilation units is unspecified.

Suppose the global data defined in `main.cpp` will be initialized before those from `mymap.cc`.   In this case `a` will be constructed before `A::myMap`. However, the constructor  `A::A()` of `a` wants to use `myMap`.  This `myMap` might have already been pre-initialized with zeroes, just in case, but its constructor has not  been invoked. All its internal pointers are null pointers. You have a segfault - and praise the compiler creators for pre-zeroing the memory devoted to `myMap`, otherwise the consequences of the error would be unpredictable.

Compare (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization):

> 3. Ordered dynamic initialization, which applies to all other non-local variables: within a single translation unit, initialization of these variables is always sequenced in exact order their definitions appear in the source code. **Initialization of static variables in different translation units is indeterminately sequenced**.